# Error saying assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

How do I resolve this? Thank you

```
    struct node
    {
    char sym[100];
    }s[20];
    int main()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       s[i].sym=i;
     return 0;
    }
```

Not sure what the problem is, When I use an array to store the integer value/ ascii value I get this error. Why is that so? For a non array variable, the input is taken without errors

Comment: Why are you trying to store an `int` value into an array object?  What do you intend to do with the `sym` member of the structure?

Answer (score 1):

What you effectively have in your code is no different to:

```
char sym[100];
sym = 0;
```

You cannot assign an integer to an array. Your code would be more likely to work with:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        s[i].sym[SOMETHING] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although, of course, you need to decide the correct value of `SOMETHING`.